# JQuery list, prevent a link to be clicked more than once

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I've been trying to figure this one out for a while now. I have a JQuery list populated using a JSon array.

Every item in the list is clickable and brings to a page called details with specific details for the item clicked.

Everything works fine, but if the user clicks several times on an item link, the page will be correctly loaded but it's gonna take several clicks on the back button to get back to the original page. Let's say the user clicks 3 times an item, when he wants to go back, he will have to hit back 3 times.

So I'm looking for a way to disable the link after it's been clicked once.

How could I accomplish that ?

Large code sample below, please tell me if my question is unclear. Thanks !

```
var items = [];


$.each(catalog.products,
      function(index, value) {

          if (
                  ((!filterValue ) || value.name.toUpperCase().indexOf(filterValue.toUpperCase()) != -1)
                          && ((!brand) || value.brand.toUpperCase().indexOf(brand.toUpperCase()) != -1)
                          && ((!category) || value.category.toUpperCase().indexOf(category.toUpperCase()) != -1)
                          && ((!sport) || value.sport.toUpperCase().indexOf(sport.toUpperCase()) != -1)
                  ) {

              var priceInfo;
              if(value.salePrice === '') {
                  priceInfo = '<h4 style="margin-top:3px;margin-bottom:0px;color:#75a8db "> $' + value.price + '</h4></a></li>';
              } else {
                  priceInfo = '<h4 style="margin-top:3px;margin-bottom:0px; "><span style="text-decoration: line-through;font-size:small;">$' + value.price +
                          '</span><span style="color:#75a8db;"> $' + value.salePrice + '</span></h4></a></li>';
              }

              items.push('<li id="' + index + '">' +
                      '<a data-identity="productId"  href="./details.page?productId=' + index + '" >' +
                      '<img class="ui-li-thumb" src="' + value.thumbnail + '"/>' +
                      '<p style="margin-bottom:0px;margin-top:0px;">' + value.brand + '</p>' +
                      '<h3 style="margin-top:0px;margin-bottom:0px;">' + value.name + '</h3>' +
                      priceInfo);



      }}
        );

if (items.length === 0) {
    items.push('<p style="text-align: left;margin-left: 10px">No results found.</p>');
}
productListView.html(items.join(''));
productListView.listview('refresh');
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you build your link as an object instead of just text, you can then bind to the click handler as you build it like this:

```
// here's the click handler you need
    itemLink.click(function(e) {
        console.log("item clicked");
        if ($(this).data("clickCount") > 0) {
            console.log("click count reached");
            return false;
        }

        console.log("following the link");
        // set a click counter
        $(this).data("clickCount", 1);
        // store the original href in case you need it
        $(this).data("ogHref", $(this).attr("href"));
        $(this).attr("href", "javascript://");
    });
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Warspawn/3A5cA/)

In the fiddle I have used your code as much as I can, but instead created the markup using jQuery objects.

Comment: Hey, I just want to say. I worked around your code a little and managed to make it work for my situation. I reallllyyy appreciate the help and the effort you put in there so thank you a million times ! Cheers !

Answer (score 1):

You can use jQuery's `one()` to implement this once-only action, for example:

```
$('a').one('click',
           function(){
               alert('hi!');
               return false;
           });
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/dt6nk/).

Or, without using `one()`, you could simply unbind the `click()` event from the element:

```
$('a').click(
       function(){
           alert('hi!');
           $(this).unbind('click');
           return false;
       });
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/dt6nk/1/).
References:

- [`one()`](http://api.jquery.com/one/).
- [`unbind()`](http://api.jquery/unbind/).

Comment: Thanks for the help. I think I get what you're trying to show me, but I'm not sure how I would implement this in my code. 

Any more clues ? Cause what I tried doesn't work.

Comment: Considering this is the link I want to disable after one click. '<a data-identity="productId" id="productClick" href="./details.page?productId=' + index + '" >' +

Answer (score 0):

```
var currentValue="";

$('a').click(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    if(currentValue != $(this).attr("href")){
        currentValue = $(this).attr("href");
        // Your actions here
    }
});
```

Thus, the link just dies when its action is the latest, but can be reused. [jsFiddle test](http://jsfiddle.net/dddH9/).

Comment: This works when I put a link in my html page, but when I try to attach this to this link : '<a data-identity="productId"  href="./details.page?productId=' + index + '" >' from my javascript file, it just won't work.

Comment: Try $('a').live('click', function(event) {...});

Comment: Still nothing. Wherever I put the code, it keeps messing up my list and returns my error message "No results were found" and the list is empty.

Really appreciate the help though. Thanks a lot.

Comment: So now it seems to work, on every link on my page, but not on this  '<a data-identity="productId" href="./details.page?productId=' + index + '" >' 

What am I doing wrong ?